# Teradata: How to extend the range partition of a non-empty partitioned table?

Tags: teradata

I have create a table, `mydb.mytable`, with essentially the following `SQL`, say **last week**:

`CREATE MULTISET TABLE mydb.mytable ,NO FALLBACK ,
     NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
     NO AFTER JOURNAL,
     CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
     DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO
     (
      master_transaction_header VARCHAR(64) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      demand_date DATE FORMAT 'YY/MM/DD',
      item_id BIGINT,
      QTY INTEGER,
      price DECIMAL(15,2))
PRIMARY INDEX ( master_transaction_header )
PARTITION BY RANGE_N(demand_date  BETWEEN DATE '2018-01-01' AND CURRENT_DATE EACH INTERVAL '1' DAY );`

When I try to insert data into it, for say **yesterday**, `teradata` gives me the following error message

`Partitioning violation for table mydb.mytable`

When I try to extend the partition using:

`ALTER TABLE mydb.mytable MODIFY PRIMARY INDEX (master_transaction_header) ADD RANGE BETWEEN DATE '2018-03-15' AND CURRENT_DATE EACH INTERVAL '1' DAY;`

I get the following error message from `teradata`:

`The altering of RANGE_N definition with CURRENT_DATE/CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is not allowed.`

I understand that I could:

1. Create a copy with `PARTITION BY RANGE_N(demand_date  BETWEEN DATE '2018-01-01' AND '9999-12-31' EACH INTERVAL '1' DAY );`
2. Insert all the data from the old table into the new one
3. drop the old table
4. rename the new table

but I am hoping that teradata provides a more elegant way to **add partitions to an existing partitioned table**.

I have already consulted the following stackoverflow posts:

- [Range partition table creation with large number of paritions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13152338/range-partition-table-creation-with-large-number-of-paritions)
- [Teradata: How to add range partition to non empty table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35870784/teradata-how-to-add-range-partition-to-non-empty-table)

They were enlightening, but I could not conjure an answer from the discussion therein.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using CURRENT_DATE for partitioning is possible, but I never found a use case for it.

When you create that table it is resolved to the *current date*,  but not changed afterwards, check the `ResolvedCurrent_Date` column in `dbc.PartitioningConstraintsV`. When you submit an `ALTER TABLE mydb.mytable TO CURRENT` it's resolved again and the range modified.

But there's no reason to do this, simply define the range large enough, so you never have to modify it again, e.g.

```
PARTITION BY RANGE_N(demand_date
                     BETWEEN DATE '2018-01-01'
                         AND DATE '2040-01-01' EACH INTERVAL '1' DAY);
```

Unused partitions have zero overhead in Teradata.

Comment: Thank you so much.  `ALTER TABLE mydb.mytable TO CURRENT` is exactly what I was looking for.  I get your point about creating partition that goes far enough into the future, but I prefer the elegance afforded by `CURRENT_DATE`.  Thank you for enabling me.

Comment: Trouble is without an empty partition for tomorrow nor a NO RANGE partition, if you do not update the partition definition daily your ETL. While elegant, I'd rather avoid the daily modification of a production table's definition for partitioning maintenance.

Comment: @RobPaller is abolutely right, but I wouldn't call it elegant, it's error prone (and even worse, when you add `NO RANGE` and forget to extend). This syntax was ment to be used with a rolling range, i.e. CURRENT_DATE for both begin and end.